# mget prompt override

Tags: ftp, command-prompt

I am using ftp in the command line (terminal) to transfer multiple data files from a remote server to my local computer.  There are multiple files (~40) in the directory and I would like to transfer them all without having to answer yes in the prompt for each file. I tried mget * but this only transferred the first file and then a prompt popped up for the second file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Issue a `prompt` command first to turn interactive prompting off.

Alternatively, if you have control over the way the ftp command is called, use the command line option, as suggested by @reg-edit:

`ftp [-i | --no-prompt] [OPTIONS] [HOST [PORT]]`

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to issuing a `prompt` command ahead of your other commands, you may invoke ftp with the `-i` switch.

Answer (score 4):

When you already started `ftp` you can issue the `prompt` command to toggle between getting prompted and not getting prompted. So this should do the trick:

```
> ftp <some server>
ftp> prompt
Interactive mode OFF .
ftp> mget *
```